# Kotlin Connect Web Hosting Sql Server

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

I have a web hosting and I created an SQL database here. The connection string I use in C# is as follows, and this connection string works:

```
<add name="NetContext" connectionString="Data Source=sql.atlas.domainhizmetleri.com,1433;Database=DbDeneme;User Id=denemeuser;Password=123456;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My problem is that despite trying to establish a connection with the connection information in the Kotlin language in Android Studio, I cannot establish a connection. Where am I making the mistake causing this error?

```
 private val ip = "sql.atlas.domainhizmetleri.com"
       private val db = "DbDeneme"
       private val un = "denemeuser"
       private val pass = "123456"
       private val port = "1433"




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in)
        val bottom_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_down)
      
        

        btngiris.setOnClickListener {
            val kullaniciAdi = txtkullanici.text.toString()
            val sifre = txtsifre.text.toString()

            if (kullaniciAdi.trim().isEmpty() || sifre.trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Kullanıcı adı ve şifrenizi giriniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                try {
                    val con = connectionclass(ip, port, db, un, pass)
                    val ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://$ip:$port;databasename=$db;User=$un;password=$pass;"

                    if (con == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "İnternet bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } else {
                        val query = "SELECT * FROM Personeller WHERE TC='$kullaniciAdi' AND Sifre='$sifre'"
                        val stmt: Statement = con.createStatement()
                        val rs: ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query)

                        if (rs.next())
                        {
                            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Dashboard::class.java)
                            val PersonelAdi = rs.getString(3)
                            val PersonelSoyAdi = rs.getString(4)
                            val PersonelTc = rs.getString(7)
                            intent.putExtra("PersonelAdi", PersonelAdi)
                            intent.putExtra("PersonelSoyAdi", PersonelSoyAdi)
                            intent.putExtra("PersonelTc", PersonelTc)
                            startActivity(intent)


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Geçersiz Kimlik Bilgileri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                        con.close()
                    }
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    ex.message?.let { it1 -> Log.e("Error", it1) }
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Bir hata oluştu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun connectionclass(ip: String, port: String, db: String, un: String, pass: String): Connection? {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build())
        var con: Connection? = null
        val ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://$ip:$port;databasename=$db;User=$un;password=$pass;"
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.message?.let { Log.e("Error", it) }
        }
        return con
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file named network_security_config.xml in the res/xml folder and add the following network security configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trusted certificates (if using HTTPS) -->
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

To update your manifest file, you can add a networkSecurityConfig attribute inside the  tag, as shown in the following example:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```